# Automating reassigning tasks to another user in Nintex Workflow

Tags: nintex-workflow

We have a requirement of reassigning all pending tasks of a user1 to another user2 when the user1 is away. We are maintaining a list wherein the status of users can be set.

Suppose if the User1's status is Away then all the tasks assigned to User1 should be reassigned to User2 and all this process should be done in Nintex Workflow itself ?

Please suggest on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need another column in your list to set the user that will receive the reassigned tasks.

Next, you have to create a new workflow associated to this list, and go to "Workflow Settings" to set "Start when items are updated" to Yes.

Finally, in your workflow you will have as current item the user who was updated (ensure that user status was changed to "Away"). Then, you just have to get the value of column you've created on first step and all tasks of current user, and assign them to the new user.

I hope it helps! ;)